# mirror modifier and multiresolution

Tags: mirror

I want to apply mirror modifier so, I did like this 
(1). In multiresolution, I changed preview 2 to 5 and save external
(2). Ctrl+A : click the Location and Scale and Rotation
(3). Applied mirror modifier
(4). In multiresolution, save external and loaded the file that I saved in (1)

but the result is very bad.... please help me! what can I do for it?
First picture is what I want
Second Picture is what I get now...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mirror cannot be on top stack of the modifiers when multires is used. Probably Blender has warned you when you applied the mirror that "applied modifier was not first, result may not be as expected". What do you aim to do exactly with the mirror and with the multires ?

Comment: If that's the final version of model, I suggest applying Multires and then mirroring mesh. Saving sculpt to external file doesn't always work as expected (or it isn't clear what to expect) so it may not save you from lot of unneeded work.